# Intercommunication between to macOS apps on local Mac

Tags: swift

Is there an easy way, in Swift, for one macOS app to send a message to another macOS app on the same mac (localhost). I have two macOS apps, one of them is a menu app. There are some situations the standard macOS app need to send a notification (a one way ticket, fire and forget) to the menu app.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of different options of how to achieve this. Each with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Probably the easiest is sending notifications using the [`DistributedNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter) from Foundation. It’s just like the regular `NotificationCenter` but across Process-Boundaries.

On the receiving side you register an observer like this:

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("com.mycompany.MyNotification"), object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in 
    print(notification) 
}
```

On the sending side you post a notification like this:

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(name: NSNotification.Name("com.mycompany.MyNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: ["data": "to send"])
```

This is not very secure though - any process can send and receive those notifications. So if they contain private data you shouldn't use this method. This also means you should use a unique notification name. Good idea to start that with a reversed DNS name like `com.mycompany.` here.

If your app is sandboxed there is another limitation that you cannot send an `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: Great, I will test it.. the message does not include private data, it is only a message to the menu app to reload data from persistent storage... Thank you for answering my question.. The app is not sandboxed (https://github.com/rsyncOSX/RsyncOSX)